# Disable plugin function

Tags: plugins, functions

I want to hide most of the backend links added by [TinyMCE Templates](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-templates/) plugin. I have problem with 'Copy to a new template' link inside Publish box. Plugin code:

```
add_action('post_submitbox_start', array(&$this, 'post_submitbox_start'));
```

I try (and it doesn't work):

```
function remove_post_submitbox_link(){
    global $tinymceTemplates;
    remove_action('post_submitbox_start', array( $tinymceTemplates, 'post_submitbox_start' ) );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'remove_post_submitbox_link', 11);
```

Why that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you've got the right idea, it won't work in this case. Taking a look at the [source code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/tinymce-templates/trunk/tinymce-templates.php), the class is simply instantiated without an assign. There's no way to get a hold of `$this` from outside the class, and so no way for you to remove the hooks it attaches itself to.

This is why I'm a strong advocate of [static methods in plugins](http://www.itsananderson.com/2011/04/php-static-methods-in-wordpress-plugins/). I would suggest contacting the author or TinyMCE Templates & asking if he would consider moving to this style of coding, or at least assigning the class instance to a global variable so that your code will indeed work.

Short term fix? Edit the plugin file & remove the `add_action` line, or use `remove_all_actions( 'post_submitbox_start' )`, though do so **with extreme caution**!